# Find the value of $xyz$

Tags: real-analysis

> $x$, $y$, $z$ are real numbers such that
>
> $①$  $ x+y+z=\sqrt{3}$
>
> $②$ $xy+yz+zx=1$
>
> In this case, find the value of $xyz$.

$$$$
Here's my attempt.

$$$$

$3=(x+y+z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +  2(xy+yz+zx) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2  + 2$

$\therefore   \ \  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 $

$\\$

$   x^3  +y^3 +  z^3    -   3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2 +  y^2  +  z^2    -  xy-yz-zx)  = 0$

$\therefore   \ \  x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 3xyz $

$\\$

**What can I do... after these?**

$$$$

I guessed the answer like this.

If $ x=y=z = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ , then these satisfy $①, ②$.

So, $\  $ $xyz=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{9}$....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y,z$ are the roots of the equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ then $a = -\sqrt 3$ and $b = 1$.

So, we want $x^3 - \sqrt 3 x^2 + x + c = 0 \equiv C$ to have all real roots.

This is nicely described by the cubic determinant $$
D_C = a^2b^2 - 4b^3 - 4a^3c - 27c^2 + 18abc
$$

being greater than or equal to $0$.

In our case, $D_C  = 3 - 4 + 12\sqrt 3c - 27c^2 - 18\sqrt 3 c = -27c^2 - 6\sqrt 3 c- 1$.

It turns out that $D_C = -27\left(c + \frac 1{3\sqrt 3}\right)^2$, giving $c = \frac {-1}{3 \sqrt 3}$.

Hence the product of the roots is $-c = \frac{1}{3 \sqrt 3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another property of [AM-GM](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/) is that if the arithmetic means and geometric means are equal, all the variables are equal.

Since $\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{3} ≥ ({x^3 \cdot y^3 \cdot z^3})^{1/3}$, we get  $x^3+y^3+z^3 ≥ xyz$, and as a consequence $x = y = z$. Therefore, you only need to solve the equation $u^3 + u^3 + u^3 = u \cdot u \cdot u$, and then substitute into equation $1$.

Comment: How can I assure $x$, $y$, $z$ are not negative...?

Comment: If the solution exists using AM-GM, then $x,y,z$ are not negative. This method works only because substituting into equation $1$ makes it true.

Comment: I said he CONDITION of AM-GM... it doesn't matter?